# What's the best way to wire a ceiling light to a light switch with this configuration

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I wanna add a light on the ceiling, and a light switch to the existing circuit.

For background, I have found a covered j box that I can connect into. I tested it and it's live, though it is a bit different than what I've seen before.

There are two different lines joined at this junction box. I'm not sure where they go. Both are Standard 2 wire with ground. So black and white tied together with ground connected to the box. Must've had a light there in the past that they put a cover over and painted.

What is the best way to do this with this configuration?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

J-box seems to be straight power in/power out(a splice).

Making a new circuit means going by new codes, so will need /3 cable to switch, hot, switch hot, and neutral(probably just capped at switch.

```
Either a light at j-box or a cable to new light position.
```

Don't know much about smart light bulbs, but might save adding a switch.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably go switch. Do you know of a diagram outlining your suggestion